# Signing in leads to /accounts/profile/ in Django

Tags: django

I have created user profiles for the user and already added

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app.ModelName'
```

But when the user successfully logs in, he/she are redirected to /accounts/profile/ by default.

How to change this? I would like them to go /profile/ and have created a view for them.

```
def Profile(request):
    '''
    profile view
    '''
    return render(request,'profile.html')
```

Comment: Just for the records. settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE was removed in Django1.7 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#features-removed-in-1-7

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the value of [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) in your settings.py.