# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in django

Tags: django, login-required

I am very new to Django and I'm nearing the end of the [django girls tutorial](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org). I have added "@login_required" above my post_detail in views (view for clicking on a specific post) and added a login.html template. So when I click on a post title I get redirected to my login page (so far, so good) and the url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/post/11/ (trying this on my computer atm.)

Then I type in my admin name/password and automatically get redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/ and of course get a "Page not found (404)" (since I have no url/view/template for that). I thought "Dang, I just wanted to be redirected to /post/11/"!

Looked around on stack overflow and found this question:
[Signing in leads to "/accounts/profile/" in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219539/signing-in-leads-to-accounts-profile-in-django) (sounds about right)
and got the answer

> Change the value of LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your settings.py.

So I looked up LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in the Django documentation:

> Default: '/accounts/profile/'
>
> The URL where requests are redirected after login **when the contrib.auth.login view gets no next parameter**.
>
> This is used by the login_required() decorator, for example.
>
> This setting also accepts named URL patterns which can be used to reduce configuration duplication since you don’t have to define the URL in two places (settings and URLconf).
>
> > Deprecated since version 1.8: The setting may also be a dotted Python path to a view function. Support for this will be removed in Django 1.10.

But doesn't my contrib.auth.login get a next parameter? (looking at my url that say "?next=/post/11/" at the end) Please help me out here, I'm lost for what the problem could be here :(

You can view the page at:
http://finbel.pythonanywhere.com/
And the source code at:
https://github.com/Finbel/my-first-blog

**UPDATE (1):**
So I now know that the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is the thing that's deciding where I end up next, which must mean that it ignores the next-parameter in the url. I googled further on the problem and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441436/the-next-parameter-redirect-django-contrib-auth-login) which was very similar to my problem, i.e.

> Documentation states that I need to use the "next" parameter and context processors. I have the {{next}} in my template, but I'm confused on how to actually pass the "/gallery/(username)". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I don't even have the {{next}} in my template, where/how should I add it?)

The preferred answer to that question seemed to be:

> Django's login view django.contrib.auth.views.login accepts a dictionary named extra_context. The values in the dictionary are directly passed to the template. So you can use that to set the next parameter. Once that is done, you can set a hidden field with name next and value {{ next }} so that it gets rendered in the template.

But I'm not sure how to interpret this. While writing this edit I got an answer on this post (by kacperd) and will read it through now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `contrib.auth.login` doesn't get the next parameter. 
When you try to get the login_required view without credentials your request is redirect to login view, and the template you created is rendered. The `next` parameter is present in this view, but when you perform the login action which is submitting the form, you are not including `next` in your request so `contrib.auth.login` doesn't get it and redirects to default page.

The solution to your problem is to include the `next` param and pass it forward. You can do this by modifying your login template. Simply add `?next={{ request.GET.next }}` to form action attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}">
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! 
Now it all makes sense :)